# Wix Burn, ignore previously installed bundle

Tags: wix, burn

I have a little Wix Burn Bundle that installed all my required components. In case of the first installation on a system, it all works fine. The installation dialog is presented, the components get installed, just as intended.

When I execute the same Bundle on the system again, I always get the uninstall/modify screen. I have set `DisableModify`, `DisableRemove` and `DisableRepair` to `yes`. What I want to have is that the Bundle always behaves the same (e.g. show the install screen), regardless of whether it has been installed to the system previously or not. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, I am not entirely sure that I understand your use case. You will not get multiple installations of your product if this is what you want (unless your components are really weird). And if the product is already installed, why would you want the user to sit through an installation wizard again?

If you just want to make the modify/repair page to look the same as the install page and run a repair when doing the second install, it might be possible to do this by customizing the [theme file](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/BalExtension/wixstdba/Resources) and provide your custom theme in your bundle wxs file.

Of course, you can always create your custom bootstrapper application as well. I would advise you to think twice before you try to change the normal way of installing things though, i.e. that they can only be installed once per context unless you change product codes and take some additional care ([more information here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369523%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Indeed, modifying the theme file solved the issue for me. Now installing for the first and second time more or less looks the same. A custom bootstrapper application would be cracking nuts with a sledgehammer, since the standard one brings all it takes for my rather simple installation chain. Thanks for your input.